# How to configure puma to establish rom-rb database connection?

Tags: heroku, puma, rom-rb

If I were using ActiveRecord, my puma config would establish the database connection as described in Heroku's guide [Deploying Rails Applications with the Puma Web Server](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/deploying-rails-applications-with-the-puma-web-server#on-worker-boot).

```
on_worker_boot do
  ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection
end
```

However, I am using [ROM](http://rom-rb.org/) (Ruby Object Mapper).

I tried omitting the `on_worker_boot` block, but (predictably) the database connection is either not established, or is not established correctly, and the following error is raised.

```
PG::ConnectionBad: PQconsumeInput() SSL error: decryption failed or bad record mac
```

I've read the [ROM Setup Guide](http://rom-rb.org/guides/basics/setup/) but did not see anything relevant.

How do I establish the ROM connection in puma?

Answer (score 3):

The solution seems to be to `disconnect` the gateway connection.

```
on_worker_boot do
  ROM.env.gateways[:default].connection.disconnect
end
```